# React Native fetch fail

Tags: react-native, http, fetch

When I use **fetch()**  method to make get request, it failed with "**TypeError: Network request failed**". It's weird that it sometimes failed but sometimes succeeded. I have tried the solution here: [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed), but it didn't work for me. By the way, I am using Android.

This is my code :

```
try {
  let url = "http://140.116.245.229:3000/GetCarsJson";

  let data = await fetch(url);
  let toJson = await data.json();
} catch(err) {
  throw err;
}
```

This is the error message :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zum3g.png)

Comment: Use axios instead of fetch

Comment: It returned the "Error: Network Error"

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure your devices/simulator/emulator can connect to this endpoint

If you use `Android emulator`, you can refer this link [How to connect to a local server from an android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668820/how-to-connect-to-a-local-server-from-an-android-emulator)

Comment: Can i ask why i should check the endpoint?

Comment: to ensure your `devices/simulator/emulator` can connect to the endpoint